# Count down function to work for test python

Tags: python, testing, while-loop

```
def test_countdown(self):
    from_3 = '3\n2\n1\nBlastoff!'
    self.assertEqual(countdown(3), from_3)
    from_0 = 'Blastoff!'
    self.assertEqual(countdown(0), from_0)
#THIS IS THE TEST
def countdown(n):
    while n>0:
        print(n)
        n=n-1
    print("Blastoff!")
#This is my code for the function
```

> It is not passing the test because on the back end it is coming out as 'none'        > for countdown(3) instead of '3\n2\n1\nBlastoff!'

Comment: You seem to have confused return values and the output from print. Print prints a value to standard output. That is entirely different from the return value of a function. You need to actually return something in order to use assertEqual.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing, not concatenating:

```
def countdown(n):
    return '\n'.join(map(str, range(n, 0, -1))) + '\nBlastoff!'
```

Or as Lalaland suggested below:

```
def countdown(n):
    result = ''

    while n > 0:
        result += str(n) + '\n'
        n = n - 1 # decrement

    result = result + '\nBlastoff!'
    return result # not printing
```

Comment: You might want to consider mirroring the style of the original code. https://gist.github.com/Lalaland/107457008470f700d1d4

Comment: It's not that great of an idea to use a while loop for a simple counter.

Comment: I agree, but clarity is sometimes important.

Comment: @SpencerJosephs This is all my code. Could you mark as answer?